# SQL result limit from Java application with spring-boot and DB2 database

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, db2, spring-boot

I'm trying to limit the sql result from some statements, for example to 100 from an application in Java using spring-boot, and a DB2 database in an AS400.

I've tryied this two things, extending a CrudRepository

```
public List<AcumuladoEstadistico> findFirst10BySincroEstado(String aEstado);
```

and also this

```java
@Query(name="FROM AcumuladoEstadistico a WHERE a.sincroEstado = ?1 limit 5", countQuery="10")
Iterable<AcumuladoEstadistico> findFirst10BySincroEstado(String aEstado);
```

but in both cases I have the following error

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [SQL0104] Símbolo LIMIT no válido. Símbolos válidos: FOR SKIP WITH FETCH ORDER UNION EXCEPT OPTIMIZE.
>       at com.ibm.as400.access.JDError.throwSQLException(JDError.java:650)
>       at com.ibm.as400.access.JDError.throwSQLException(JDError.java:621)
>       at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCStatement.commonPrepare(AS400JDBCStatement.java:1557)
>       at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCPreparedStatement.(AS400JDBCPreparedStatement.java:193)
>       at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnection.prepareStatement(AS400JDBCConnection.java:2025)
>       at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnection.prepareStatement(AS400JDBCConnection.java:1824)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:81)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy61.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:162)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186)
>       ... 69 more

Why I have this problem, maybe Hibernate doesn't create the statement properly for DB2? What can I do?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: try writing FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY instead of limit 5, and see if it works. this is the db2 way to limit the result

Comment: I used too and throw another exception. Finally I've found the problem i explain in the answer. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've found the problem, I was using an incorrect dialect in the properties of sping

Thanks a lot!